# Evaluate a pair of integrals of the product of two univariate functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

There is a claim (and multiple-page proof) in the literature (a citation to which I can [and do below] give) that

$\frac{64}{3}$ times the integral over $t \in [0,1]$ of the product of

```
(27 t^2 (1 - t^2) + 11 (1 - t^6) + 
   6 (1 + t^2) (1 + 8 t^2 + t^4) Log[t])/(-1 + t^2)^7
```

and

```
(4 (t + t^3 - (-1 + t^2)^2 ArcTanh[t]))/(π^2 t^3)
```

equals $\frac{1}{4}$. I have been unable to support this claim in Mathematica through either (perhaps naive) numerical or symbolic means.

Further, in a related matter, I am interested in evaluating the integral, again over $t \in [0,1]$ of the product of

```
(t^3 (11 + 27 t^2 - 27 t^4 - 11 t^6 + 
  6 (1 + 9 t^2 + 9 t^4 + t^6) Log[t]))/(420 (-1 + t^2)^7)
```

and

```
(2 (-t + t^3 + ArcTanh[t] - t^4 ArcTanh[t] + 
  t^2 (4 PolyLog[2, t] - PolyLog[2, t^2])))/(π^2 t^2)
```

There is presently no claim/conjecture for this result.

Of possible interest here is that the second of the four functions given above is the (FullSimplify) derivative of the last of the four.

To return to the first of the two integration problems, the authors of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf claim on p. 13 that $\frac{64}{3}$ times the indefinite integral over $t$ equals

```
-(9 (t^2 - 1)^6 PolyLog[2, 1 - t] + 9 (t^2 - 1)^6  PolyLog[2, -t] + 
96 (t^2 + 1) (t^4 + 28 t^2 + 1) (t^2 - 1)^3 ArcTanh[t] + 
9 (t^8 - 132 t^6 - 378 t^4 - 132 t^2 + 1) (t^2 - 1)^2 Log[t] Log[
  t + 1] + 
2 t (-57 t^10 - 1211 t^8 + 78 t^6 - 78 t^4 + 1211 t^2) + 
6 t ((-3 t^10 + 401 t^8 + 882 t^6 + 882 t^4 + 401 t^2 + 
      192 + (t^9 + t^7 - 4 t^5 + t^3 + t) Log[1 - t] - 3) Log[
     t] + 57))/(9 Pi^2 (t^2 - 1)^6)+const
```

So, can Mathematica be employed to yield this result and/or, at least make plausible, the $\frac{1}{4}$ result for the definite integral over $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: You have something wrong in your question. The result I get is 32.9699061836 from numerical integration. Not any where near 0.25

Comment: You could add the citation. It might help someone spot the problem.

Comment: This assertion can be found on p. 13 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf. The first of the two functions is explicitly given there. The second function is the derivative $\chi_1(\varepsilon)'(t)$ of the function $\chi_1(\varepsilon) $ given Subscript[\[Chi], 1] (\[Epsilon]) = 
  1 - (4/Pi^2) Integrate[(s + 
        1/s - (1/2) (s - 1/s)^2 Log[(1 + s)/(1 - s)])/s, {s, 
      0, \[Epsilon]}]] in eq. (9) of the paper. (Evaluation of the integral in eq. (9) gives the last of the four functions in the original question.)

Comment: Bill--there is one integration to be performed over the product of the two functions--not the product of two integrations. Sorry, if the question was not clear enough.

Comment: One small point to begin--in my extended comment above, I should have been using $\tilde{\chi_1}$, to fully conform with the notation, rather than $\chi_1$ itself. (The tilde normalizes the function to be 1 at $\varepsilon=1$.)  More substantively, I see that elsewhere in the cited paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf, such as pp. 15, 16 there are similar-looking integrals but where $\tilde{\chi_1}$ is used and not its derivative. Quick numerics then give a result somewhat closer to the $\frac{1}{4}$, but still nowhere near.

Comment: In the third comment above, $\varepsilon=t$, and the derivative should then be written as $(\tilde{\chi}_1)'(t)$.